# How is function executing outside of this for loop?

Tags: python, function

Why is this function executing outside of the For loop and stopping when the iterative step has completed?

```
def train():

    w1 = np.random.randn() #random number from normal distribution
    w2 = np.random.randn() #random number from normal distribution
    b = np.random.randn()  #random number from normal distribution
    iterations = 100000    #number of iterations
    learning_rate = 0.02    #learning rate

    for i in range(iterations):

        randpoint = data[np.random.randint(len(data))]
        pred = activation(randpoint[0] * w1 + randpoint[1] * w2 + b)
        cost = (pred - randpoint[2])**2

        dcost_dpoint = 2 * (pred - randpoint[2]) * (der_activation(randpoint[0] * w1 + randpoint[1] * w2 + b))

        w1 = w1 - learning_rate * dcost_dpoint * randpoint[0]
        w2 = w2 - learning_rate * dcost_dpoint * randpoint[1]
        b = b - learning_rate * dcost_dpoint  

    return w1, w2, b

w1, w2, b = train()
```

Comment: This line is at the bottom of the cell in jupyter notebook w1, w2, b = train()

Comment: Do not understand how having these values at the end restarts the function but does not alter the iterations variable?

Comment: Where is `data` object defined?

Comment: data is defined earlier in the notebook data = [[3,   1.5, 1],
        [2,   1,   0],
        [4,   1.5, 1],
        [3,   .25,   0],
        [3.5, .5,  1],
        [2,   .5,  0],
        [5.5,  1,  1],
        [1,    1,  0]]

Comment: this is just a simple machine learning algorithm but i just dont understand this call "w1, w2, b = train()" outside the function.   i may rewrite the code using a while loop unless i can figure out what this call at the end does?

Comment: `w1, w2, b = train()` is setting those three variables to the return value of `train()`. Also you need to specify what kind of activation function you're using (what the import is)

Comment: The last line is calling the function. What is not  clear?

Comment: im using sigmoid activation. excuse me i havent use this site before will be more descriptive in the future. thanks for the help.

Comment: i just dont understand that the last line calls the funcion and passes through the new W1, W2, B but i dont get how the iterations step isnt restarted when the function is called again

Comment: There is no "new" W1, W2, or B. First you *define* the function, then you call it *once*, and it returns the values computed inside the function  and assigns them to a *different* set of variables with the same name.

Comment: It doesn't pass "the new value", or indeed any value at all. The values are what is *returned* from the function. It's hard to understand what is confusing you here: this is just a normal function call which returns three values.

Comment: Why does the funciton return the values when i change w1, w2, b = train() to just train() at the end?

Comment: It sounds like you just don't understand the basic concept of calling functions and returning values from them. This is common to practically all programming languages, and is a fundamental idea in programming.

Comment: If you change it to just `train()`, the function runs, but the results are discarded because you don't assign them to anything.

Comment: i understand now. thank you for all your help. hope everyone has a nice day. sorry for asking such a simple question. but seriously thanks again i get it now.

Answer (score 1):

> i just dont understand this call "w1, w2, b = train()" outside the function.

This causes the `train()` function to execute. Without a function call, none of the code inside of the function will do anything.

Note that `train()` returns several values. Technically, it returns a **tuple** with three values. You can assign the returned value to a variable

```
r = train()
```

Then later you can refer to the elements in the tuple:

```
print(r[0])
print(r[1])
print(r[2])
```

Often we want to give names to each of the elements:

```
w1 = r[0]
w2 = r[1]
b = r[2]
```

Python provides a shorthand for this by assigning directly from the returned value of the function:

```
w1, w2, b = train()
```

> but i dont get how the iterations step isnt restarted when the function is called again

To clarify this comment, the function is only called **once** in the entire code you posted and that occurs on this line. The previous `def train():` **defines** the function so that it can be used at any time later.

Comment: i just called train at the end instead and now it's working. i just used train() instead of w1,w2,b = train(). i cannot understand the difference in this line of code.

Comment: it works either way i just have never seen the variables put before the function like that. but i am new so thank you for all your help i appreciate it.

Comment: The `w1` *inside* the function is a completely different variable than the `w1` *outside* the function. The one inside goes away after the function exits.

Comment: @soundremedy Have you ever seen something like `line = input()`? That has a variable before the function . The only difference here is that there's more than one variable, which you can do if the function returns multiple values, like `return w1, w2, b`

Comment: @soundremedy Each value in the `return` statement gets assigned to the corresponding variable in the function call.

Comment: @soundremedy I added some more details to explain this syntax. I suggest that you take some time to learn about functions and "function call" as well as "variable assignment" and "tuples". These are two key concepts in python.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank you so much for your help. it made my day. i appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The instruction `w1, w2, b = train()` says: invoke a function `train ()` which should return a triple of values, and assign the first value from the triple to `w1`, the second one to `w2` and the third one to `b`.

That's how functions work: first you define a function once, then you invoke it when you need it, possibly / usually many times.